# Можно ли компилировать только используемый код?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Допустим есть class подключенный к проекту, в котором записаны все основные функции, которые я использую для построения приложений. Я просто вызываю нужную мне функцию, в нужный момент. Их в классе много. Вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли сделать так, чтобы компилятор компилил в приложение только те функции, которые вызывались из класса, а не весь класс? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Заголовок вашего вопроса не соответствует правилам, принятым в сообществе. Пожалуйста, измените его так, чтобы он отражал суть вопроса

Comment: Ну и за что минус-то?

Comment: Да тут минусы без причины, как и вот такие комментарии. Не стоит сильно заморачиваться с ними.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нельзя сделать стандартными средствами компилятора. Можно сделать при помощи утилит, называемых обфускаторами - они, кроме запутывания кода, обычно умеют вырезать неиспользуемый код.

В мелких проектах это просто не имеет практического смысла - вы просто не можете написать достаточное количество кода, чтобы он *значительно* повлиял на размер результирующей сборки.

В крупных проектах такой подход сомнителен по некоторым причинам:

- нельзя вырезать public методы - они могут вызываться из других сборок.
- нельзя вырезать реализации интерфейсов - для для таких методов не будет прямых вызовов в коде.
- нельзя вырезать вирутальные методы т.к. они всега вызываются неявно.
- вырезание может поломать вызов методов через reflection - опять же, из-за возможности вызова метода "по имени".

Крупный проект обычно подразумевает Interface Segregation (много интерфейсов) и использованием IOC/DI - вызов всего через интерфейсы, а не напрямую. Т.о. почти все методы становятся невырезаемыми или публичными, явно или неявно.

Т.е. безопасно из крупного проекта можно вырезать пару процентов кода, не больше. Никто не будет рисковать ради пары килобайт.

Кроме того, "неиспользуемый" код никак не влияет на производительность. Он просто лежит в виде пачки данных (IL) на диске на диске. В реальный (машинный) код методы преобразуется при первом вызове метода. Нет вызова - нет преобразования, нет затрат.

Comment: Хорошо расписал. Но у него просто модуль с набором функций, который он хочет включать во все свои программы (вряд ли крупные), причём так, чтобы те, которыми он не воспользуется не включались в exe.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да. Но я просто скорее хотел сказать "ничего страшного что лишний код попадает в exe, все так делают и не заморачиваются", чем реально как-то помочь вырезать код

Comment: На мой взгляд, недостаток не в лишнем коде в exe, а в самой идее сложить все глобальные функции для разных проектов в один модуль.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, но нельзя краткий курс проектирования и хотя бы пару лет опыта уместить в одном ответе )

Comment: Ковырять исходники смотреть зависимости, копипастить нужное пока не заробит

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Компилируется всегда всё полностью.

Возможно, какой-то обфускатор попробует выпилить неиспользуемые функции, но тут ничего точно сказать не могу.

Вообще, Лучше этот твой класс поделить на классы логически и таскать только нужные.

Answer (score 0):

Используй директивы компилятора:

```
   #If DEBUG Then
      Sub Test()
         Console.WriteLine("Only for debugging...")
      End Sub
   #End If

   #If Not DEBUG Then
      Sub RealFunc()
         Console.WriteLine("For release...")
      End Sub
   #End If
```