# Сборка только используемых частей зависимостей

Tags: java, компиляция

Допустим у меня есть определенный проект, который использует N дополнительных библиотек. В сумме они все немало занимают места, однако от общего объема функционала библиотек используется около 20%. Есть ли какое-то автоматизированное средство, которое может проследить используемые сущности и собрать их, допустим в основной исполнительный jar, дабы уменьшить общее кол-во занимаемого места?

Знаю, уже был похожий вопрос: [Можно ли компилировать только используемый код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434302/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Но ведь на основе анализа кода можно явно определить какие реализации интерфейсов используются (не все же инстанцируется с помощью фабрик, да и там неиспользуемые реализации можно заменить "пустышками"), и что создается через рефлексию(насчет последнего не очень уверен, т.к. мало практического опыта). Плюс, возможно за год появилось какое-либо, зарекомендовавшее себя решение.

Comment: посмотрите proguard https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard